# Is language of a sexual nature,which is an intregal part of the sentence in question, allowed

Tags: discussion

Is language of a sexual nature,which forms an intregal part of the sentence in question, allowed.Example.
:    *Richard J Ingram. Vice Chairman of the ailing “Home World Pleasures. Inc.”  slipped his shiny blue new Electron across the early morning traffic flow, and hung for a while in the slow lane, barley moving at all.

“F*****g gridlocked as usual.” said his passenger.

“So what’s new…and glancing at the sidewalk he exclaimed. F***, would you just look at the way the girls a** moves, Crossthread,”*

I hope I have put this in the correct section, if not please help and redirect me.JAB

Comment: Keep profanity out of the title whenever possible. Everything else is fair game. An English word is an English word.

Comment: Why is the barley being moved?

Comment: @oerkelens Clearly to make room for the a**.